# Checkstyle gradle Unable to instantiate AvoidConstantAsFirstOperandInConditionCheck when checking style

Tags: gradle, checkstyle, sevntu-checkstyle

I have configured my Gradle build script to make use of checkstyle together with the added sventu checkstyle checks, however when I execute the checkstyleMain task, the build fails with the following error:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':checkstyleMain'.
> Unable to create a Checker: cannot initialize module TreeWalker - Unable to instantiate AvoidConstantAsFirstOperandInConditionCheck
```

This happens even though I have included the checkstyle jar in my build. Below is the relevant parts of my build script:

```
repositories {
      mavenCentral()
      maven {
          url "http://sevntu-checkstyle.github.com/sevntu.checkstyle/maven2"
      }
   }

checkstyle {
    configFile = new File("etc/config/dev.xml");
    toolVersion = "6.8"
}

configurations {
    checkstyle
}

dependencies {  
    checkstyle "com.github.sevntu.checkstyle:sevntu-checks:1.13.4"
}
```

Note that the build works when I remove the dependencies section and test with a checkstyle xml doc that does not have the extra sevntu checks configured. My configuration is also similar to the example at [sevntu-checkstyle/checkstyle-samples](https://github.com/sevntu-checkstyle/checkstyle-samples/blob/master/gradle-project/build.gradle)

What am I missing here?

Comment: In the example you provided dependencies are declared inside `checkstyle` block.

Comment: Ive made the modification however now I get a different error. Its looks like the sventu library is not picked up?

Answer (score 3):

So I finally figured it out:

Turns out the example at https://github.com/sevntu-checkstyle/checkstyle-samples/blob/master/gradle-project/build.gradle only works if you put the full classpath of the custom checks as the name for each custom check.

This is due to checkstyle not knowing where the custom checks are located in the package. Turns out checkstyle can find this out if you include a checkstyle_packages.xml file in the jar that describes the packages that contains the checks.

Unfortunately there is no such file in com.github.sevntu.checkstyle:sevntu-checks:1.13.4. To get this information, you also need to include "com.github.sevntu.checkstyle:sevntu-checkstyle-maven-plugin:1.13.4", which basically contains nothing but the checkstyle_packages.xml file.

So I've added this to my dependencies and the checkstyle rules finally parses:

```
dependencies {
    checkstyle "com.github.sevntu.checkstyle:sevntu-checks:1.13.4",
               "com.github.sevntu.checkstyle:sevntu-checkstyle-maven-plugin:1.13.4"
}
```

Hoping this will save someone some pain in future :)